# how to stop click event on ion-item for conditional items ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to disable click on `ion-item` for some items.
The code is something like this

```
<ion-item class="item (app.app_id==='isDivider')?'item-divider':'' no-border padding-20-10"
        collection-repeat="app in apps"
        item-width="(app.app_id==='isDivider')?5000:90"
        item-height="(app.app_id==='isDivider')?70:105"
        ng-click="(app.app_id==='isDivider')||listDetailsOfApps();item.clicked = true"
        stop-event="click">
```

It is actually now not calling if `app.app_id` is `isDivider` but still clickable.

How to make it not clickable as it is header and should not be clickable

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a $scope function in your controller to detect and run other actions for clickable item:

#### Controller:

```
$scope.clickCheck = function(app){
    if(app.app_id==='isDivider'){
        //action for the divider. (should do nothing)
    }else{
        //action for the clickable item. (set item.clicked=true)
    }
}
```

#### View :

Repeat item inside `<div>` tag and using `ng-if`:

```
<div collection-repeat="app in apps">
    <ion-item ng-if="app.app_id==='isDivider'" class="item-divider no-border padding-20-10"
        item-width="5000"
        item-height="70">
    <ion-item ng-if="app.app_id!=='isDivider'" class="no-border padding-20-10"
        collection-repeat="app in apps"
        item-width="90"
        item-height="105"
        ng-click="item.clicked=true">
</div>
```

Comment: It is still clickable... I want it to not be clickable. as of now I have made pressed color to be as unpressed color. But this is just an hack

Comment: Oh Now I understand what are you trying to do, let me update the answer.